# Git merge compare from to meaning

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I wonder for the git Compare View's from and to fields, when a 'Merge Request' is made, is the merge is made so that, the branch in **from** will be merge into the **to**? or vise versa? I do not want to trigger the request without understand the concept of it.

I have two branches one is feature, another is develop. I wonder should I put the feature in the from field and compare develop in to field in this case?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a merge, the "from" is typically the source branch, and the "to" would be the destination branch where the replays will take place.

```
$ git checkout destination-branch

$ git merge source-branch
```

In this case, you would be merging the changes *from* `source-branch` *to* `destination-branch`.

If you think of ***from*** as the "source branch", and ***to*** as the "destination" branch, that should be a common workflow as above you can transfer to git clients and remotes.